# overflow-y property not work with position sticky left

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside another table, and both tables' first and second  elements are sticky to the left. I need the inner table to be scrollable if there is more data. Currently, the sticky functionality is working, but when I enable the scroll-y: auto property, the sticky functionality stops working.

For better understanding,
I created a
`codepen`[Code pen](https://codepen.io/arul-k/pen/RwEQWJO)